# Going through a video in OpenCV is extremely CPU intensive, why isn't watching a video as intensive?

Tags: opencv

If if I watch an H264 encoded video locally, I'll barely see any effect on my CPU. (I have no GPU).

But, if I walk frame by frame through the same video with the following code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path_to_video)
while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
```

My CPU usage explodes. Why is this? what am I doing different here vs when I'm just watching a video locally in VLC or Quicktime?

Comment: Ignoring the fact that this code wouldn't run at all, since `grab()` just returns a boolean (which won't unpack into 2 values), you're telling the computer to grab all the frames from a video as quickly as possible. With no GPU to help, seeing the CPU fully utilized would be the expected outcome.

Comment: Edited my question! Shouldn't OpenCV be using hardware acceleration via the CPU?

Comment: What kind of hardware acceleration do you have in mind? (i.e. what device would be performing all the calculations?)

Answer (score 0):

For VLC/quicktime, probably software optimization/hardware acceleration (offloading to your GPU) are allowing the software to do this much easier on your cpu.

Python as an interpreted language (and depending on your system config) doesn't have the same optimizations.

Comment: Hi! Sorry, just added to my post that I don't have a dedicated GPU. Does this change your answer at all?

Comment: Most systems have an integrated gpu, In Device Manager look for something like Intel HD5450 Graphics.  I would suspect, without knowing more about your setup, the answer is that video watching programs have been compiled (in the case of quicktime/vlc) to work at a much lower level and are much faster because of that

Comment: probably a gpu or vpu

Comment: OpenCV is implemented in C++. The amount of work the interpreter does in that 3-liner is negligible.